# Check HTTP request against reliable server

Tags: android, http

In my android app i keep getting timeouts in the messages between the app and my server.
In an attempt to see if the problem is in the app or my server,
i want to try and Send an HTTP request from my app to
some other server i am sure is up and reliable and then see if i get timeouts.
Is there any server address i can check against?
Thanks in advance!
BTW : i am using a glass Fish servlet for my server

Comment: www.google.com, www.wikipedia.org, stackoverflow.com, ...

Comment: Pick your favourite search engine?

Comment: Not sure how reliable this is going to be, what if it's a DNS issue?

Comment: well i guess that makes sense :p thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've successfully sent a simple HTTP GET to google.com -- with a couple of fall-backs (I've also seen internic.org used) in the past, in similar cases.